# Unable to run Code Coverage since update 14.1.1 in IntelliJ

Tags: java, intellij-idea, code-coverage

Since I update my **IntelliJ** to **14.1.1**, I am unable to run Code Coverage.

I can run Test without any problem, but the Code Coverage button always gives me this error :

```
FATAL ERROR in native method: processing of -javaagent failed
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.loadClassAndStartAgent(InstrumentationImpl.java:386)
    at sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.loadClassAndCallPremain(InstrumentationImpl.java:401)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at com.intellij.rt.coverage.main.CoveragePremain.premain(CoveragePremain.java:66)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Le chemin d’accès spécifié est introuvable
    at java.io.WinNTFileSystem.createFileExclusively(Native Method)
    at java.io.File.createNewFile(File.java:1012)
    at com.intellij.rt.coverage.data.ProjectData.createProjectData(ProjectData.java:92)
    at com.intellij.rt.coverage.instrumentation.Instrumentator.premain(Instrumentator.java:75)
    ... 11 more
Exception in thread "main" 
Process finished with exit code 1
```

I thought at first I did something wrong when updating and I reinstalled it, but it's still not working.

Comment: No idea ? :( No one ever had this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEABKL-5941#comment=27-421957
That can help

> Workaround:
> Add this line
>
> -Djava.io.tmpdir=C:\Temp
>
> to the idea.exe.vmoptions file (in C:\Program Files\ideaIU-11.1.4\bin)
> And make sure the C:\Temp exists.